# Adding a view to UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have created a `UIView`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinGreen_v1.png"];
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PinDown1.png"];

        UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 40, 40)];
        [btn1 setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:btn1]; 

        for(int i =1; i<20; i++){
            UIButton *btn2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40 * i, 40, 40, 40)];
            [btn2 setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn2 addTarget:self 
                     action:@selector(buttonPressed) 
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self addSubview:btn2];
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

With the above code I am drawing images in my view. I am loading this view from my view controller. I need to put this view inside a `UIScrollview`. Where should I create the scroll view? In the above view or the view controller where the above view is created.

The code inside my view controller is :

```
 DrawLineInMyClass *drawLines = [[DrawLineInMyClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
 drawLines.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [self.view addSubview:drawLines];
 [drawLines release];
```

I should be able to scroll through the images inside my view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create the the scrollview in the viewcontroller and add the view to it.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

DrawLineInMyClass *drawLines = [[DrawLineInMyClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
drawLines.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:drawLines];

[scroll addSubview:drawLines];

scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*drawLines.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[drawLines release];
[scroll release];
```

Comment: both these lines? if your adding it to scroll also to view? [self.view addSubview:drawLines];
[scroll addSubview:drawLines];